# Give a generating set for $Syz(h_1,h_2,h_3,h_4)$

Tags: polynomials

I have a question which asks for a generating set of Syz($h_1,h_2,h_3,h_4$)

where

$h_1=x^2y+z^2$

$h_2=zy^2+yx^3$

$h_3=xz-y^2$

$h_4=y^4+yx^4$

I know that it is formed by...

$Syz(h_1,h_2,...h_m)=$ {$\alpha \in R^m | \alpha_1h_1+\alpha_2h_2+....+\alpha_mh_m=0$}

Can anyone help me with how to use this to answer the question.. In lectures we only went through a very simple answer that you could see how to solve, as it was obvious